# Columns collapse

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

Some random columns collapse while using the foundation zurb grid, why?

```
<div class="small-centered">
    <div class="row small-12 small-centered">   
      <?php foreach ($videos as $video): ?>
          <div class="column small-6 medium-4 large-4">
              <div>short text</div>
              <img src="https://placehold.it/150x150" />
          </div>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]
The blank area is not an empty div.

EDIT: here is the html and css output
[image]

Comment: Nothing looks out of the ordinary. Without knowing Zurb Foundation and making an educated guess we're left in the dark... can you post the HTML that gets output with Inspect Element?

Comment: @JackHasaKeyboard I added a screenshot

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

you need to add an `.end` to your last element. use a counter and modify your `foreach` loop like this (you might need to adjust it a little bit:

```
<?php 
$i = 0;
$len = count($videos);
foreach ($videos as $video): 
    if ($i == $len - 1) { 
        echo '<div class="column large-4 end">'; //this is the last
    } else { 
        echo '<div class="column large-4">'; // if not last-echo normally...
    } ?>
                  <div>short text</div>
                  <img src="https://placehold.it/150x150" />
              </div>
    <?php $i++;
endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I edited the code and the result is scattered columns, and why should I use a clearfix if I didn't used float classes?

Comment: oh, look here: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/grid.html#incomplete-rows - you need to add .end to your last element or override the sass settings that causes that. @ImriPersiado

Comment: How can I add .end to the last element if the last element is not the same in different devices (small, medium and large) ?

Comment: i've modified my answer. check it now

Comment: corrected the count() line. you can try now @ImriPersiado

Comment: I think that you don't understand me and maybe that because of me, the website is planned to run on multi device that's why I used zurb. In the code above the small-x and medium-y is missing but I'm using them. with your solution I will be able to put the end class only for one of them. I corrected my code.